# Unit Test for retrofit2.Call

Tags: android, unit-testing, retrofit2

Since Retrofit 2.6.0 has support for Coroutines and the library of kotlinCoroutinesAdapter is deprecated I started to refactor my API calls. I changed it and is working fine but I have problems with Unit Tests.

This is how I had my calls:

```
//Retrofit API
@GET("playlists/{playlistId}")
    fun getPlaylistAsync(@Path("playlistId") id: String): Deferred<PlaylistData>

//DataSource
fun getPlaylistAsync(playlistId: String): Deferred<PlaylistData> = playlistApi.getPlaylistAsync(playlistId)

//Repository
override suspend fun getPlaylist(playlistId: String): PlaylistDomain {
        val playlistDeferred = remoteDataSource.getPlaylistAsync(playlistId)
        return playlistRemoteMapper.map(playlistDeferred.await())
    }
```

And this is what I changed to make it work:

```
//Retrofit API
@GET("playlists/{playlistId}")
    fun getPlaylistAsync(@Path("playlistId") id: String): Call<PlaylistData>

//DataSource
fun getPlaylistAsync(playlistId: String): Call<PlaylistData> = playlistApi.getPlaylistAsync(playlistId)

//Repository
override suspend fun getPlaylist(playlistId: String): PlaylistDomain {
        val playlistDeferred = remoteDataSource.getPlaylistAsync(playlistId)
        return playlistRemoteMapper.map(playlistDeferred.await())
    }
```

Basically is the same... the await() used with Deferred and with Call is different but everything else is so similar.

As I said the problems comes with the test. Here I have what I did for the first example:

```
@Test
fun `getPlaylist() maps correctly the playlist and the favorite request when is favorite`() = runBlocking {
    val playlist = PlaylistDataBuilder().getPlaylistData(id = PLAYLIST_ID)

    every { playlistDataSource.getPlaylistAsync(PLAYLIST_ID) } answers { async { playlist } }

    val response = playlistRepository.getPlaylist(PLAYLIST_ID)

    assertTrue(response.isFavorite)
}
```

Now I want to change this to fit the second example... but async returns a Deferred and now I need Call to fit my needs. I tried to mock Call and do the following:

```
@Test
fun `getPlaylist() maps correctly the playlist and the favorite request when is favorite`() = runBlocking {
    val playlist = PlaylistDataBuilder().getPlaylistData(id = PLAYLIST_ID)
    every { playlistCall.await() }

    every { playlistDataSource.getPlaylistAsync(PLAYLIST_ID) } answers { playlistCall }

    val response = playlistRepository.getPlaylist(PLAYLIST_ID)

    assertTrue(response.isFavorite)
}
```

The problem here is that playlistCall.await() must be into a suspend method so I cannot make it work this way. I would need a way to make a Unit Test for retrofit Call.